# (FD WENO) Correct characteristic decomposition of 2D Euler equations

Tags: finite-difference

After successful implementation of characteristic-wise finite-difference WENO method to 1D Euler equations, I'm moving to 2D equations on cartesian grid:
$$
\frac{\partial U}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial F(U)}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial G(U)}{\partial y} = 0
$$
where
$$
U = \left( \begin{array}{c} \rho \\ \rho u \\ \rho v \\ e\end{array} \right), \quad 
F(U) = \left( \begin{array}{c} \rho u \\ \rho u^2 + p \\ \rho uv \\ (e+p)u\end{array} \right), \quad
G(U) = \left( \begin{array}{c} \rho v \\ \rho uv \\ \rho v^2 + p \\ (e+p)v\end{array} \right), \quad
$$

According to Shu's guidebook, numerical method for 2D case is quite simply derived from 1D case:
$$
\frac{dU_{ij}}{dt} = - \frac{1}{\Delta x} \left( \hat{f}_{i+\frac{1}{2}, j} - \hat{f}_{i-\frac{1}{2}, j} \right) - \frac{1}{\Delta y} \left( \hat{g}_{i, j+\frac{1}{2}} - \hat{g}_{i, j-\frac{1}{2}} \right)
$$
where $\hat{f},\hat{g}$ are found by 1D WENO method using corresponding eigenmatrices for $F(U)$ and $G(U)$.

The matrices I found in literature are (notation used: $q = \frac{u^2+v^2}{2},\; a=\sqrt{\frac{\gamma p}{\rho}}, \; h=\frac{a^2}{\gamma-1} + q$):
$$
J_f = \frac{\partial F(U)}{\partial U} = \left( \begin{array}{cccc}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
(\gamma-1)q-u^2 & (3-\gamma)u & (1-\gamma)v & \gamma-1\\
-uv & v & u & 0\\
\Big((\gamma-1)q-h\Big)u & h-(\gamma-1)u^2 & (1-\gamma)uv & \gamma u
\end{array}\right)
$$
$$
R_f = \left( \begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
u-a & u & u+a & 0\\
v & v & v & -1\\
h-au & q & h+au & -v
\end{array}\right), \quad \lambda_f=(u-a,\;u,\;u+a,\;u)
$$
$$
L_f = R^{-1}_f = \left( \begin{array}{cccc}
\frac{(\gamma-1)q+au}{2a^2} & \frac{(1-\gamma)u-a}{2a^2} & \frac{(1-\gamma)v}{2a^2} & \frac{(\gamma-1)}{2a^2}\\
\frac{a^2-(\gamma-1)q}{a^2} & \frac{(\gamma-1)u}{a^2} & \frac{(\gamma-1)v}{a^2} & \frac{(1-\gamma)}{a^2}\\
\frac{(\gamma-1)q-au}{2a^2} & \frac{(1-\gamma)u+a}{2a^2} & \frac{(1-\gamma)v}{2a^2} & \frac{(\gamma-1)}{2a^2}\\
v & 0 & -1 & 0
\end{array}\right)
$$
These are used to calculate fluxes over x-direction ($\hat{f}$).

Also:
$$
J_g = \frac{\partial G(U)}{\partial U} = \left( \begin{array}{cccc}
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
-uv & v & u & 0\\
(\gamma-1)q-v^2 & (1-\gamma)u & (3-\gamma)v & \gamma-1\\
\Big((\gamma-1)q-h\Big)v & (1-\gamma)uv & h-(\gamma-1)v^2 & \gamma v
\end{array}\right)
$$
$$
R_g = \left( \begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
u & u & u & 1\\
v-a & v & v+a & 0\\
h-av & q & h+av & u
\end{array}\right), \quad \lambda_g=(v-a,\;v,\;v+a,\;v)
$$
$$
L_g = R^{-1}_g = \left( \begin{array}{cccc}
\frac{(\gamma-1)q+av}{2a^2} & \frac{(1-\gamma)u}{2a^2} & \frac{(1-\gamma)v-a}{2a^2} & \frac{(\gamma-1)}{2a^2}\\
\frac{a^2-(\gamma-1)q}{a^2} & \frac{(\gamma-1)u}{a^2} & \frac{(\gamma-1)v}{a^2} & \frac{(1-\gamma)}{a^2}\\
\frac{(\gamma-1)q-av}{2a^2} & \frac{(1-\gamma)u}{2a^2} & \frac{(1-\gamma)v+a}{2a^2} & \frac{(\gamma-1)}{2a^2}\\
-u & 1 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right)
$$
These are used to calculate fluxes over y-direction ($\hat{g}$).

The correctness of the matrices have been tested numerically: they satisfy $
LR=E$, $LJR = \Lambda = \text{diag}(\lambda_i)$ for both $F$ and $G$.

Obviously, the code for $x$-wise and $y$-wise WENO reconstruction is very symmetrical: just substitute correct matrices and use array differences along [j] index instead of [i].

Here is my problem: when I test the program on simple stationary shock normal to $x$-axis, everything is OK. But for similar test for $y$-axis, some instability grows in the uniform-state area ahead of the shock. I still can't find any asymmetry in my code; is it possible that I'm using matrices incorrectly? Maybe the order of eigenvalues and eigenvectors should be different $(\lambda_y=(v-a,\; v,\; v,\; v+a)$, for example)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I think nobody will be able to benefit from this as the answer was an "undescribed bug"

Comment: Will the question itself still be visible and thus "googlable"? If so, I can't have any objections to closing the question.

Answer (score 0):

After 10th or 20th code sweep I finally found the bug in it.
Quick tests show that everything is OK now, method works nice.
Let this question hang in here for as a help for future googlers of 2D Euler decomposition.

Comment: Appreciated, I'm just learning finite volume methods myself.

Comment: Does it work with bugs?

Comment: @nicoguaro the bug was in code, not in formulas here - they are correct.

Comment: So, why is this an useful answer?

Comment: @nicoguaro At this moment, the thread looks like: "question: Am I using right formulas? answer: Yes, right ones". I'm not sure how should it be properly archived. Obviously, the information contained in the question itself is useful (see 1st commenter)...

Comment: @omican I voted to close this question as its not really a question and it keeps getting bumped up automatically.